# Compiler Error doesn't make sense (error is missing parameter to function)

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting a compiler error of:

error: no matching function for call to `buildTransFunc(<unresloved overloaded function type>, boost::function<EnumType(short int)>, EnumTypeToStringTranslator&)`

The declaration for buildTransFunc is as follows:

```
template<typename RT, typename func, typename... Args>
RT buildTransFunc(func f, Args... args)
{
    return RT(boost::bind(f, _1, args...));
}
```

I am calling the above as follows:

```
typedef boost::function<std::string (short int)> toASCIITranslator;
toASCIITranslator temp = buildTransFunction<toASCIITranslator, std::string (*) (short int, boost::function<EnumType(short int)>, EnumTypeToStringTranslatorType&), boost::function<EnumType(short int)>, EnumTypeToStringTranslatorType& >
(&Translator<std::string, forward_trans, short int, boost::function<EnumType (short int)>, EnumTypeToStringTranslatorType>, boost::function<EnumType(short int)(&enumChecker), EnumTypeToStringTranslator);
```

The error message seems to be skipping over the std::string (*) (short int, boost::function, EnumTypeToStringTranslatorType&) parameter in the error message, as everything else is in there.

I'm using GCC 4.5.2 for the compiler.

The declaration for the Translator function is:

```
template<typename RT, typename D, typename... Args>
RT Translator(Args... args)
{
    return static_cast<RT>(translate<RT, D>(args...));
}
```

The translate functions can be found in this question:
[Translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579692/c-template-function-question)

**EDIT**
corrected call to buildTransFunction to finish specifing parameters.

g++ arguments used: -std=c++0x.

Comment: You're using a C++0x feature (variable template argument list). Have you told the compiler to compile C++0x?

Comment: yes, I have added the -std=c++0x to the argument list for the compiler.

Comment: You must have weird code. Why is it that `&enumChecker` gives you a `boost::function<>`? Also, where did you declare `f`? All that doesn't look like real code. Also we need the declaration of `Translator`.

Comment: sorry. updated based on your comment Johannes. Need to double check things more, since its posted via typing instead of copy-paste, as development system is not connected to internet. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the moral of this question is don't try to be too fancy... as this works by
plainly calling boost::bind with the parameters, instead of forwarding them though a seprate function.

so instead of this:

```
toASCIITranslator temp = buildTansFunc<.....>(....);
```

just do the call like this:

```
toASCIITranslator temp = boost::bind(&Translator<std::string, forward_trans, short int, boost::function<EnumType(short int), EnumToStringTranslatorType&>, 
                         _1, 
                         boost::function<EnumType(short int)>(&enumChecker),
                         EnumToStringTranslator);
```